# ¿Cómo tener normalmente no seleccionados los layers, en Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Al crear los layers, normalmente se visualiza el mapa con los checked o marcas seleccionados (se visualizan). La idea es que normalmente estén sin seleccionar (mapa sin marcas) y según se seleccionen se vayan visualizando los elementos o las marcas en el mapa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ejemplo de código:**

```
L.marker([{{ latitud }}, {{ longitud }}],{icon: plcIcon}).bindPopup('<a>Prueba</a>').addTo(ctl);

    var overlays = {
    "CTL":ctl
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde se no hay un método nativo, pero se puede hacer `.removeLayer` cuando carga la página, algo asi:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  
  for (var i in layers) {
    map.removeLayer(layers[i]);
  }
  
});
```

Eso deja los checks destildados.